# Compare values in a row and write result in new column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, split, string-matching

My dataset looks like this:

```
Paste_Values AB_IDs AC_IDs    AD_IDs
AE-1001-4 AB-1001-0  AC-1001-3 AD-1001-2
AE-1964-7 AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7 AD-1964-1
AE-2211-1 AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3 AD-2211-2
AE-2182-4 AB-2182-6  AC-2182-7 AD-2182-5
```

I need to compare all values in the  `Paste_values` column with the all other three values in a row.

For Example:

AE-1001-4 is split into two part `AE` and `1001-4` we need check `1001-4` is present other columns or not

if its not present we need to create new columns put the same `AE-1001-4`

if  `1001-4` match with other columns we need to change it inot 'AE-1001-5' put in the new column

After:

If there is no match I need to to write the value of `Paste_values` as is in the newly created column named `new_paste_value`.

If there is a match (same value) in other columns within the same row, then I need to change the last digit of the value from `Paste_values` column, so that the whole value should not be the same as in any other whole values in the row and that newly generated value should be written in `new_paste_value` column.

I need to do this with every row in the data frame.

So the result should look like:

```
Paste_Values AB_IDs AC_IDs    AD_IDs     new_paste_value
AE-1001-4 AB-1001-0  AC-1001-3 AD-1001-2   AE-1001-4
AE-1964-7 AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7 AD-1964-1   AE-1964-3
AE-2211-1 AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3 AD-2211-2   AE-2211-4
AE-2182-4 AB-2182-6  AC-2182-4 AD-2182-5   AE-2182-1
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from defining a function to be applied to each row of your DataFrame:

```
def fn(row):
    rr = row.copy()
    v1 = rr.pop('Paste_Values')   # First value
    if not rr.str.contains(f'{v1[3:]}$').any():
        return v1  # No match
    v1a = v1[3:-1] # Central part of v1
    for ch in '1234567890':
        if not rr.str.contains(v1a + ch + '$').any():
            return v1[:-1] + ch
    return '????'  # No candidate found
```

A bit of explanation:

The *row* argument is actually a *Series*, with index values taken from
column names.

So *rr.pop('Paste_Values')* removes the **first** value, which is saved in *v1*
and the **rest** remains in *rr*.

Then *v1[3:]* extracts the "rest" of *v1* (without "AE-")
and *str.contains* checks each element of *rr* whether it
contains this string at the end position.

With this explanation, the rest of this function should be quite
understandable. If not, execute each individual instruction and
print their results.

And the only thing to do is to apply this function to your DataFrame,
substituting the result to a new column:

```
df['new_paste_value'] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

To run a test, I created the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    ['AE-1001-4', 'AB-1001-0', 'AC-1001-3', 'AD-1001-2'],
    ['AE-1964-7', 'AB-1964-2', 'AC-1964-7', 'AD-1964-1'],
    ['AE-2211-1', 'AB-2211-1', 'AC-2211-3', 'AD-2211-2'],
    ['AE-2182-4', 'AB-2182-6', 'AC-2182-4', 'AD-2182-5']],
    columns=['Paste_Values', 'AB_IDs', 'AC_IDs', 'AD_IDs'])
```

I received no error on this data. Perform a test on the above data.
Maybe the source of your error is in some other place?

Maybe your DataFrame contains also **other** (*float*) columns,
which you didn't include in your question.
If this is the case, run my function on a copy of your DataFrame,
with this "other" columns removed.

Comment: when trying your code I am getting this error TypeError: ("'float' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 7000')

Comment: Look at row with index == 7000. Maybe it contains any "illegal" value? There should be **only** strings. Where did you take any *float* value from?

Comment: here my dataset type Paste_Values    object
AB_IDs          object
AC_IDs          object
AD_IDs          object
dtype: object

Comment: I still suppose that the problem is somewere in your data. Run my code e.g. on the first half and second half of your source data. The next test is to repeat the run on halves of the "failed" input part.